# How to mark the icons according to the GPS coordinates on the map-captured image?

Tags: android, coordinates

1. Capture a map, create an image, and display it on the screen.
2. The image has a start point and an end point.
3. Rotate the image so that the starting point is always to the left, regardless of the actual orientation.
4. The image is fixed and the user cannot zoom/rotate the image.
5. The coordinates of the four vertices(a,b,c,d) are obtained from the server.
6. I used a captured image in the question, but Google Maps cannot be used because the app uses a custom image.

How do I display an icon on the image when I have received specific coordinates within the map area?

image on real map(`top is north`)
[image]

image on screen(`top is east`)
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to overlay an icon on a picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65198970/is-it-possible-to-overlay-an-icon-on-a-picture)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi No. That is just show/hide icon. I want to change the position where the icon is displayed whenever the gps coordinates change.

Comment: You just update the position. Or your problem is about how to get new position from time to time?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi When I get a list of coordinates for multiple people from the server, I want to display an icon. Getting coordinates from the server is not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Help from https://thecodinglog.github.io/math/javascript/2019/04/25/convert-gps-to-screenxy.html

My android code https://github.com/susemi99/GpsToScreen

**Actual Map**
[image]

**Rotate slightly clockwise(map1)**
[image]

**Rotate `map1` 180 degrees(map2)**
[image]

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
      GpsToScreenTheme {
        val viewModel = viewModel<MainActivityViewModel>()

        Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
          Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center) {
            Row() {
              TextButton(onClick = { viewModel.setupMap1() }) {
                Text(text = "map1")
              }
              TextButton(onClick = { viewModel.setupMap2() }) {
                Text(text = "map2")
              }
            }

            Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
              Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = viewModel.mapImage.value),
                contentDescription = "",
                modifier = Modifier
                  .fillMaxWidth()
                  .onSizeChanged { viewModel.updateMapViewSize(it) },
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
              )

              viewModel.pins.forEach { PinIcon(it) }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @Composable
  private fun PinIcon(offset: IntOffset) {
    var iconSizeOffset by remember { mutableStateOf(IntOffset.Zero) }

    Column(
      horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
      modifier = Modifier
        .offset { iconSizeOffset }
        .onSizeChanged {
          iconSizeOffset = IntOffset(offset.x - it.width / 2, offset.y - it.height)
        },
    ) {
      Icon(Icons.Default.LocationOn, contentDescription = "", tint = Color.Yellow)
    }
  }
}
```

**MainActivityViewModel**

```
   class MainActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {
  private val _mapImage = mutableStateOf(R.drawable.map_1)
  val mapImage: State<Int> = _mapImage

  private val _mapViewSize = mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero)
  val mapViewSize: State<IntSize> = _mapViewSize

  private var leftTopLocation = Location("")
  private var rightTopLocation = Location("")
  private var leftBottomLocation = Location("")

  private var theta = 0.0
  private var longitudeEquation = LinearEquation(0.0, 0.0)
  private var latitudeEquation = LinearEquation(0.0, 0.0)

  private val _pins = mutableStateListOf<IntOffset>()
  val pins: SnapshotStateList<IntOffset> = _pins

  fun updateMapViewSize(size: IntSize) {
    if (size == mapViewSize.value) {
      return
    }

    _mapViewSize.value = size
    setupMap1()
  }

  fun setupMap1() {
    _mapImage.value = R.drawable.map_1

    leftTopLocation = Location("").apply {
      latitude = 37.583744
      longitude = 126.502398
    }

    rightTopLocation = Location("").apply {
      latitude = 37.901339
      longitude = 127.765617
    }

    leftBottomLocation = Location("").apply {
      latitude = 37.027601
      longitude = 126.723336
    }

    calculateLocation()
  }

  fun setupMap2() {
    _mapImage.value = R.drawable.map_2

    leftTopLocation = Location("").apply {
      latitude = 37.345171
      longitude = 127.988737
    }

    rightTopLocation = Location("").apply {
      latitude = 37.027601
      longitude = 126.723336
    }

    leftBottomLocation = Location("").apply {
      latitude = 37.901339
      longitude = 127.765617
    }

    calculateLocation()
  }

  private fun calculateLocation() {
    val leftTopGpsPosition = GpsScreenPosition(0, 0, leftTopLocation.latitude, leftTopLocation.longitude)
    val rightTopGpsPosition = GpsScreenPosition(mapViewSize.value.width, 0, rightTopLocation.latitude, rightTopLocation.longitude)
    val leftBottomGpsPosition = GpsScreenPosition(0, mapViewSize.value.height, leftBottomLocation.latitude, leftBottomLocation.longitude)

    theta = calcTheta(
      convertUnitToLat(leftTopGpsPosition.longitude),
      leftTopGpsPosition.latitude,
      convertUnitToLat(rightTopGpsPosition.longitude),
      rightTopGpsPosition.latitude
    ) * -1

    val horizontalCoordinatesAfterRotation = calcCoordinatesAfterRotation(
      convertUnitToLat(leftTopGpsPosition.longitude), leftTopGpsPosition.latitude,
      convertUnitToLat(rightTopGpsPosition.longitude), rightTopGpsPosition.latitude, theta
    )
    horizontalCoordinatesAfterRotation.x = convertUnitToLon(horizontalCoordinatesAfterRotation.x.toDouble()).toFloat()
    rightTopGpsPosition.rotatedLongitude = horizontalCoordinatesAfterRotation.x.toDouble()
    rightTopGpsPosition.rotatedLatitude = horizontalCoordinatesAfterRotation.y.toDouble()

    val verticalCoordinatesAfterRotation = calcCoordinatesAfterRotation(
      convertUnitToLat(leftTopGpsPosition.longitude), leftTopGpsPosition.latitude,
      convertUnitToLat(leftBottomGpsPosition.longitude), leftBottomGpsPosition.latitude, theta
    )
    verticalCoordinatesAfterRotation.x = convertUnitToLon(verticalCoordinatesAfterRotation.x.toDouble()).toFloat()
    leftBottomGpsPosition.rotatedLongitude = verticalCoordinatesAfterRotation.x.toDouble()
    leftBottomGpsPosition.rotatedLatitude = verticalCoordinatesAfterRotation.y.toDouble()

    longitudeEquation = makeLinearEquation(leftTopGpsPosition.longitude, leftTopGpsPosition.x.toDouble(), rightTopGpsPosition.rotatedLongitude, rightTopGpsPosition.x.toDouble())
    latitudeEquation = makeLinearEquation(leftTopGpsPosition.latitude, leftTopGpsPosition.y.toDouble(), leftBottomGpsPosition.rotatedLatitude, leftBottomGpsPosition.y.toDouble())

    showLocationPin()
  }

  private fun showLocationPin() {
    _pins.clear()
    _pins.add(locationToIntOffset(37.386341, 127.893554))
    _pins.add(locationToIntOffset(37.515625, 127.297432))
    _pins.add(locationToIntOffset(37.827975, 127.674172))
    _pins.add(locationToIntOffset(37.162741, 126.776208))
    _pins.add(locationToIntOffset(37.555538, 126.623294))
    _pins.add(locationToIntOffset(37.237769, 127.426801))
  }

  private fun locationToIntOffset(lat: Double, lng: Double): IntOffset {
    val rotation = calcCoordinatesAfterRotation(
      convertUnitToLat(leftTopLocation.longitude), leftTopLocation.latitude,
      convertUnitToLat(lng), lat, theta
    )
    rotation.x = convertUnitToLon(rotation.x.toDouble()).toFloat()
    val x = longitudeEquation.slope * rotation.x + longitudeEquation.intercept
    val y = latitudeEquation.slope * rotation.y + latitudeEquation.intercept
    return IntOffset(x.toInt(), y.toInt())
  }

  private fun calcDistancePer(): PointF {
    val distancePerLat = leftTopLocation.distanceTo(Location("temp").apply {
      latitude = leftTopLocation.latitude + 1
      longitude = leftTopLocation.longitude
    }) / 1000 // 1경도당 거리(km)
    val distancePerLon = leftTopLocation.distanceTo(Location("temp").apply {
      latitude = leftTopLocation.latitude
      longitude = leftTopLocation.longitude + 1
    }) / 1000 // 1위도당 거리(km)

    return PointF(distancePerLat, distancePerLon)
  }

  private fun convertUnitToLat(lonValue: Double): Double {
    val distancePer = calcDistancePer()
    return lonValue * distancePer.y / distancePer.x
  }

  private fun convertUnitToLon(latValue: Double): Double {
    val distancePer = calcDistancePer()
    return latValue * distancePer.x / distancePer.y
  }

  private fun calcTheta(origin_x: Double, origin_y: Double, x: Double, y: Double): Double {
    val a = y - origin_y
    val b = x - origin_x
    return atan(a / b)
  }

  private fun calcCoordinatesAfterRotation(x1: Double, y1: Double, x2: Double, y2: Double, theta: Double): PointF {
    val rebasedX = x2 - x1
    val rebasedY = y2 - y1

    val rotatedX = rebasedX * cos(theta) - rebasedY * sin(theta)
    val rotatedY = rebasedX * sin(theta) + rebasedY * cos(theta)

    val xx = rotatedX + x1
    val yy = rotatedY + y1

    return PointF(xx.toFloat(), yy.toFloat())
  }

  private fun makeLinearEquation(x1: Double, y1: Double, x2: Double, y2: Double): LinearEquation {
    val x = x2 - x1
    val y = y2 - y1
    val slope = y / x
    val intercept = y1 - (slope * x1)
    return LinearEquation(slope, intercept)
  }
}
```

**LinearEquation**

```
data class LinearEquation(
  val slope: Double,
  val intercept: Double
)
```

**GpsScreenPosition**

```
data class GpsScreenPosition(
  val x: Int,
  val y: Int,
  val latitude: Double,
  val longitude: Double,
  var rotatedLongitude: Double = 0.0,
  var rotatedLatitude: Double = 0.0
)
```